# AngularJS - Pass parameter to filter in custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to pass a parameter (true, false) to a filter in a custom directive, but I always get an 'undefined'.

```
<job jobs="jobs" activateFilter="activateFilter">
```

In a controller (outside of customDirective):

```
$scope.activateFilter = true;
```

This is the directive:

```
...
restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            jobs: "=jobs",
            activateFilter: "=activateFilter"
        },
        controller: controller,
        templateUrl: "/views/templates/job.html"
...
```

And this is the template:

```
... data-ng-repeat="job in jobs | customFilter:activateFilter ...
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? activateFilter is always undefined.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the attribute name to lower case and dash-delimited:

```
<job jobs="jobs" activate-filter="activateFilter">
```

See [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) under Normalization and Isolating the Scope of a Directive

> Note: These =attr attributes in the scope option of directives are
>   normalized just like directive names. To bind to the attribute in div
>   bind-to-this="thing", you'd specify a binding of =bindToThis.

Comment: Solution:
`$scope.activateFilter = true;`

`<job jobs="jobs" activate-filter="activateFilter">`

Directive:
`activateFilter: "=activateFilter",`

`data-ng-repeat="job in jobs | jobfilter:activateFilter"`